# Flutter Project not running on android Emulator

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter.

I am now using VSCode IDE with Flutter extension.

With the `flutter doctor -v`, it shows OK except Windows apps which I don't intent to develop.

Also, I have run some *.dart and it works fine.

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.3155], locale zh-TW)
    • Flutter version 3.19.0 on channel stable at D:\Download\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision bae5e49bc2 (13 days ago), 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.82.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.3155]
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.69
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 122.0.2365.52

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

---

Then, I create and connect to a android emulator (Pixel 6 API 34), after I `Start Debugging` the example from [main.dart](https://github.com/tonycheng-0118/Dart_Study/blob/master/proj_hello_world/lib/main.dart), it shows like the following snapshot.

[image: https://imgur.com/7Jc5ji9.]

And stuck at `Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...` forever.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

BR,

Tony.

If I change to connect to Chrome for web app, it works.

Comment: ig, there some problem from the emulator, try to reinstall the android sdk, or try to create a new emulator. since it work fine in both android and ios

Comment: Hi @Stanly, Thanks for comments. Had tried to created a new one with different API version, but failed as before. 
Will keep looking for solution to try!

Comment: try to build it rather than debug it, or even try to run flutter run --stacktrace on the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the root cause of failing to run on the android emulator.

The failure signature is

```
Your project path contains non-ASCII characters.
```

By using commdline `flutter run .\lib\main.dart` instead of the `Start Debugging` button, the failing msg are printed.

After change to a new dir, the android emulator are OK to use.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score -1):

Above problem specific to the Android emulator setup or the interaction between Flutter and the emulator. Here are several steps you can take to diagnose and resolve the issue.

**Update Flutter SDK**

Ensure your Flutter SDK is up to date. Sometimes, bugs that affect deployment to emulators are fixed in newer versions

```
flutter upgrade
```

**Cold Boot the Emulator**

Sometimes, the emulator can get into a bad state.
You can try cold booting it

- Open the AVD Manager in Android Studio.
- Find the emulator that'scausing problems.
- Click on the dropdown menu on the right, and select "Cold Boot Now."

**Increase Emulator's RAM**

If the emulator is running out of memory, it might fail to launch apps properly. Increase the allocated RAM.

**Installing Visual Studio for Windows Development**

Sometimes this warning might be causing this issue. Install it and check whether the above error still persist.

**Recreate the Emulator**

If none of the above steps work, try deleting the current emulator and creating a new one from the AVD Manager. Sometimes, emulator configurations can become corrupted.

Comment: Hi @Mrex, thanks for those suggestions.
Had tried all of the action you suggest, and I even reinstall the VSCode and Android Studio.
But, it now only works in web app (by Chrome and Edge), don't work on Android emulator or Window app.
Still looking for the way to test.
Will share in this post once I have solved the issue (hope not too long :"| ) .

Thanks you!

BR, 
Tony